# ImageGalleryControl not triggering

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to download an image in bytes from a server, but the image won't display. I get a proper byte array and resize it. It works adding picture from the camera but doesn't work when adding them from the internet.

I've confirmed that the image is saved correctly, and downloaded properly as I can copy the byte Array and display it using the byte array string.

I found the problem comparing the two methods while debugging, and in the `execturepickcommand` it triggers my `"ItemSourceChanged"` method but it doesn't trigger with the `AddImages` method.

The Collection

```
public class ImageGalleryPageModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> Images
    {
        get { return images; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ImageModel> images = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();
}
```

This works adding the Pictures from this class

```
private async Task ExecutePickCommand()
{
    MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

    if (file == null)
        return;

    byte[] imageAsBytes;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
        file.Dispose();
        imageAsBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    if (imageAsBytes.Length > 0)
    {
        IImageResizer resizer = DependencyService.Get<IImageResizer>();
        imageAsBytes = resizer.ResizeImage(imageAsBytes, 1080, 1080);

        ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
        Images.Add(new ImageModel { Source = imageSource, OrgImage = imageAsBytes });
    }
}
```

Then I download the images and put them into the Collection,

```
private void AddTheImages(int imageIssueId)
{
    var imageData = App.Client.GetImage(imageIssueId);

    byte[] imageAsBytes = imageData.Item1;

    if (imageAsBytes.Length > 0)
    {
        IImageResizer resizer = DependencyService.Get<IImageResizer>();
        imageAsBytes = resizer.ResizeImage(imageAsBytes, 1080, 1080);

        ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
        ImageGalleryViewModel.Images.Add(new ImageModel { Source = imageSource, OrgImage = imageAsBytes });
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<freshMvvm:FreshBaseContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" 
                                xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                                xmlns:freshMvvm="clr-namespace:FreshMvvm;assembly=FreshMvvm"
                                xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ASFT.Converters;assembly=ASFT"
                                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ASFT.Controls;assembly=ASFT"
                                x:Class="ASFT.Pages.IssuePage" 
                                Padding="4,25,4,4" 
                                x:Name="IssuePages">
    ...
    <!--PictureGallery-->
    <Label Text="IMAGES" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
           Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" 
           TextColor="White" />
    <Grid BindingContext="{Binding ImageGalleryViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="128" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <controls:ImageGalleryControl Grid.Row="0" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
            <controls:ImageGalleryControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Source}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFit">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PreviewImageCommand, Source={x:Reference IssuePages}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ImageId}" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:ImageGalleryControl.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:ImageGalleryControl>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" 
                    Text="Add photo" 
                    Command="{Binding CameraCommand}" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="Pick photo" 
                    Command="{Binding PickCommand}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" 
           Grid.Row="3" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
           Text="{Binding ImageText}" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
           TextColor="White" />
    ...
</freshMvvm:FreshBaseContentPage>
```

And this is the Control, it is the itemsourcechanged which is what is not triggering.

```
    private readonly StackLayout imageStack;
    public ImageGalleryControl()
    {
        this.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal;

        imageStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };

        this.Content = imageStack;
    }

    public new IList<View> Children
    {
        get { return imageStack.Children; }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<ImageGalleryControl, IList>
        (
            view => view.ItemsSource,
            default(IList),
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanging: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => 
            {
                ((ImageGalleryControl)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanging();
            },
            propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => 
            {
                ((ImageGalleryControl)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
            }
        );

    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    private void ItemsSourceChanging()
    {
        if (ItemsSource == null)
            return;
    }

    private void CreateNewItem(IList newItem)
    {
        View view = (View)ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
        if (view is BindableObject bindableObject)
            bindableObject.BindingContext = newItem;
        imageStack.Children.Add(view);
    }

    private void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, IList oldValue, IList newValue)
    {
        if (ItemsSource == null)
            return;

        if (newValue is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyCollection)
        {
            notifyCollection.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => 
            {
                if (args.NewItems != null)
                {
                    if (args.NewItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (object newItem in args.NewItems)
                        {
                            View view = (View)ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
                            if (view is BindableObject bindableObject)
                                bindableObject.BindingContext = newItem;
                            imageStack.Children.Add(view);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    imageStack.Children.Clear();
                    foreach (object item in ItemsSource)
                    {
                        View view = (View)ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
                        BindableObject bindableObject = (BindableObject) view;
                        if (bindableObject != null)
                            bindableObject.BindingContext = item;
                        imageStack.Children.Add(view);
                    }
                }
                if (args.OldItems != null)
                {
                    // not supported
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<ImageGalleryControl, object>
        (
            view => view.SelectedItem,
            null,
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => 
            {
                ((ImageGalleryControl)bindable).UpdateSelectedIndex();
            }
        );

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    private void UpdateSelectedIndex()
    {
        if (SelectedItem == BindingContext)
            return;

        SelectedIndex = Children
            .Select(c => c.BindingContext)
            .ToList()
            .IndexOf(SelectedItem);

    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedIndexProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<ImageGalleryControl, int>
        (
            carousel => carousel.SelectedIndex,
            0,
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => 
            {
                ((ImageGalleryControl)bindable).UpdateSelectedItem();
            }
        );

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    private void UpdateSelectedItem()
    {
        SelectedItem = SelectedIndex > -1 ? Children[SelectedIndex].BindingContext : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work without the resizer? Try saving downloaded image to disk and opening it - maybe there is something wrong with your bytes

Comment: Doesn't work without the reziser, nothing wrong with the bytes, I tested them on a page that takes a byte-Array and  converts it into a image, displays the image perfectly but nothing happens when the excat same Array goes into the collection

Comment: have you tried web client for downloading image ? var webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData("http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"); Not sure will it be helpful here or not .

Comment: Yep, tried that too. Not sure why, why the one case of adding images works and the other one doesn't. They are almost same. Only difference is I get the other file from internet the other one from the phone camera.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're adding them to the same instance of ImageGalleryPageModel?

Comment: Actually No, but not sure how to check that.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but in AddTheImages, you're adding them to ImageGalleryViewModel, but you've got the Observnable collection defined on ImageGalleryPageModel.  Is that just an instance?

Comment: For anyone viewing this today. Please don't use this code. It's horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to Raise Propertychanged event for Images Property like : PropertyChanged(nameof(Images)).
2. Then to verify you are on the same ViewModel instance, you can subscribe on BindingContextChanged event in your page and verify either your VM object is changing or not.
3. I would suggest using ObservableCollection as:

   `public ObservableCollection<> Images {get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<>();`

with a generic ImageModel.
You don't need a private field, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Hey dude, thanks for answering. But this is an almost 3 year old post haha and I've since long improved enough to write way better code, heck even Xamarin has improved so much. 

Accepted your answer anyways m8